# Adding open/closed icon to Twitter Bootstrap collapsibles (accordions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've set up this simple version of the Bootstrap [accordion](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse):

**Simple accordion:**
http://jsfiddle.net/darrenc/cngPS/

Currently the icon only points **down**, but does anyone know what JS would be needed to be implemented so as to change the class of the icon to:

```
<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
```

...so that it points **up** when **expanded** and toggles back to **down** again when collapsed, and so fourth?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Here it's the answer for those who are looking for a solution in Bootstrap 3(like myself).

### The HTML part:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="demo" class="collapse in">Some dummy text in here.</div>
```

### The js part:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

---

### Example accordion:

[Bootply accordion example](http://bootply.com/89084)

Comment: exactly whats needed for bootstrap 3.x.  if using 2.x remove `.bs.collapse`. I also changed `shown and hidden to show and hide` so the animation happens before the accordion opens.

Comment: this should be the right answer because it runs in version 4 too

Comment: How about for nested accordions?  the child elements don't have chevrons but I am still getting the switch on the parent.

Answer (score 48):

Here is my approach for Bootstrap 2.x. It is just some css. No JavaScript needed:

```
    .accordion-caret .accordion-toggle:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .accordion-caret .accordion-toggle:hover span,
    .accordion-caret .accordion-toggle:hover strong {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .accordion-caret .accordion-toggle:before {
        font-size: 25px;
        vertical-align: -3px;
    }
    .accordion-caret .accordion-toggle:not(.collapsed):before {
        content: "▾";
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    .accordion-caret .accordion-toggle.collapsed:before {
        content: "▸";
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
```

Just add class *accordion-caret* to the accordion-group div, like this:

```
<div class="accordion-group accordion-caret">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
            <strong>Header</strong>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really liked this approach Martin. Specially because is very unobtrusive.

Comment: I found this to work with one exception - the initial caret is always showing expanded for all sections. Once you expand and then collapse again, it is correct.

Comment: @Robb - I included the "collapsed" class on my "collapse" element in the html to resolve the issue with the initial arrow. My html is a little different but it'll probably work

Comment: I like the css solution as well. Some of my peers are more comfortable in css than javascript, so this was a better solution for my team. Thanks for addressing the initialization part. Now it works great!

Answer (score 42):

The Bootstrap Collapse has some Events that you can react to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#accordProfile').on('shown', function () {
       $(".icon-chevron-down").removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-up");
    });

    $('#accordProfile').on('hidden', function () {
       $(".icon-chevron-up").removeClass("icon-chevron-up").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
    });
});
```

Comment: Muffls, you are a star! nice and simple too, thanks for that ;-)

Comment: you're welcome! you could also use show or hide instead of shown and hidden. Try it out. You will see which one you prefer.

Comment: Hi Muffs, any ideas why this won't work on my live test site? http://datascrew.co.uk/gordonedge.com/

Comment: add $(document).ready(... in you main.js
I've put the code above.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much, THAT has been driving me bonkers! :-)

Comment: Every jQuery code has to be surrounded by that. No Problem, you're welcome

Comment: Bootstrap3: Events names needs to have .bs.collapse, so they are on('hide.bs.collapse') and on('show.bs.collapse'), or shown/hidden when you want to add more css transitions to it.

Answer (score 22):

Use CSSes pseudo-selector :after using Bootstrap 3's integrated Glyphicons for a **no JS answer** with minor modification to your HTML...

**CSS**

```
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after
{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e072"; /* "play" icon */
    float: right;
    color: #b0c5d8;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;

    /* rotate "play" icon from > (right arrow) to down arrow */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:    rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:     rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:      rotate(-90deg);
    transform:         rotate(-90deg);
}
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after
{
    /* rotate "play" icon from > (right arrow) to ^ (up arrow) */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:    rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:     rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:      rotate(90deg);
    transform:         rotate(90deg);
}
```

**HTML**

Add `class="collapsed"` to any anchor tags that are closed by default.

This will turn anchors such as

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
```

into

```
<a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
```

**CodePen Live Example**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYobER

**Screenshot**

[image: How it appears in JSBin]

Comment: this jsbin link has been reported

Comment: Moved it over to CodePen. Thanks for reporting. Give it a try!

Answer (score 16):

Added to @muffls answer so that this works with all twitter bootstrap collapse and makes the change to the arrow before the animatation starts.

```
$('.collapse').on('show', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".icon-chevron-left").removeClass("icon-chevron-left").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
}).on('hide', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".icon-chevron-down").removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-left");
});
```

Depending on your HTML structure you may need to modify the `parent()`.

Comment: +1 dropped it in & it worked for me - just modified to use icon-chevron-right instead of left

Comment: This one works for me. Other codes changes class for all the tabs when clicked instead of the clicked tab :)

Answer (score 10):

I think the best codes are these:

```
  $('#accordion1').collapse({
    toggle: false
  }).on('show',function (e) {
        $(e.target).parent().find(".icon-chevron-down").removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-up");
      }).on('hide', function (e) {
        $(e.target).parent().find(".icon-chevron-up").removeClass("icon-chevron-up").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
      });
```

Comment: This is the only working solution for me, rest toggle the class of all the accordion-groups. Cheers :)

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is interested this is how you do it with BS3 since they changed the event names:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
  var i = $(this).parent().find('i')
  i.toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
  var i = $(this).parent().find('i')
  i.toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-right');
});
```

You simply change the class names in the example to the ones you use in your case.

Comment: Thanks b3rgstrom, appreciated. I'll check that out when I next use BS3.

Comment: No probs, thought that someone might find your question in the future with the same problem :)

Answer (score 5):

The most readable CSS-only solution would probably be to use the aria-expanded attribute. Remember that you'll need to add aria-expanded="false" to all collapse-elements as this is not set on load (only on first click).

#### The HTML:

```
<h2 data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Title
</h2>
```

#### The CSS:

```
h2[aria-expanded="false"] span.glyphicon-chevron-down,
h2[aria-expanded="true"] span.glyphicon-chevron-right
{
    display: none;
}

h2[aria-expanded="true"] span.glyphicon-chevron-down,
h2[aria-expanded="false"] span.glyphicon-chevron-right
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Works with Bootstrap 3.x.

Comment: This works perfectly. Because my anchor tag was the data-toggle, I simply changed the h2 to a in the CSS

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution which is further refined from one posted by @john-magnolia and solves some of its issues

```
/**
 * Toggle on/off arrow for Twitter Bootstrap collapsibles.
 *
 * Multi-collapsible-friendly; supports several collapsibles in the same group, on the same page.
 */
function animateCollapsibles() {

    $('.collapse').on('show', function() {
        var $t = $(this);
        var header = $("a[href='#" + $t.attr("id") + "']");
        header.find(".icon-chevron-right").removeClass("icon-chevron-right").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
    }).on('hide', function(){
        var $t = $(this);
        var header = $("a[href='#" + $t.attr("id") + "']");
        header.find(".icon-chevron-down").removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-right");
    });
}
```

And here is the example markup:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion-send">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-send" href="#collapse-refund">
                <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Send notice
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-refund" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum Toholampi city</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good people - I feel the grand idiot, but cannot get either of these solutions to work :-S the only difference I can think of is that i use the new bootstrap3, and hence get the classes "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right. Any pointers?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is not backwards compatible release. Please refer to Bootstrap 3 documentation how to migrate the code.

Comment: Hello, Mikko, thank you, yes I gathered that, and got good help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147338/twitter-bootstrap-3-0-icon-change-on-collapse

Answer (score 3):

A bootstrap v3 solution (where the events have different names), also using only one jQuery selector (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14928493/637423)):

```
$('.accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse', function (n) {
    $(n.target).siblings('.panel-heading').find('i.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

Comment: Excellent Answer

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it without any js.

I used the icon glyphicon-triangle-right but it works with any other icon, what it does is that it applies a 90 degrees rotation to the icon when the panel is open or not. I'm using **Bootstrap 3.3.5** for this one.

CSS Code

```
h4.panel-title a {
    display: block;

}
h4.panel-title a.collapsed .glyphicon-triangle-right {
        color: #ada9a9 !important;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
}
h4.panel-title a .glyphicon-triangle-right {
        color: #515e64 !important;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

This is the HTML structure taken from the Bootstrap example

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                            Proven Expertise
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

Comment: This method works for me, but the initial status is rotated by 90deg. Could you kindly suggest how to make initial status unrotated (0deg)? Thanks!

Comment: In the anchor elements add the class="collapsed" to avoid what's happening to you

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually tried '<h4 class="panel-title collapsed">' but have no luck. Would this be correct?

Comment: It has to be on the anchor tag because is what bootstrap js changes when the onClick event fires, check on this page ,is working with the solution I mentioned http://www.acubavoy.com/preguntas-frequentes

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me but I came up with this and it worked:

```
function toggleChevron(el) {
  if ($(el).find('i').hasClass('icon-chevron-left'))
      $(el).find('.icon-chevron-left').removeClass("icon-chevron-left").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
  else 
      $(el).find('.icon-chevron-down').removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-left");
}
```

HTML implementation:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion-send">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading" onClick="toggleChevron(this)">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-send" href="#collapse-refund">
        <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Send notice
      </a>
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

@RobSadler:

RE Martin Wickman's CSS only version...

You can get around that problem by putting accordion-caret on the anchor tag and giving it a collapsed class by default.  Like so:

```
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle accordion-caret collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
        <strong>Header</strong>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrup 3.2 + FontAwesome

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#accordProfile').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".fa-chevron-down").removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    });

    $('#accordProfile').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    });
});
```

Sometimes you have to write so. If so

```
$('.collapsed span').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
```

Automatically generated (class="collapsed"), when you press the hide menu.

ps when you need to create a tree menu

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered by numerous ways but what I came up with was the simplest and easiest for me with Bootstrap 3 and font awesome. I just did

```
$('a.toggler').on('click', function () {$('i', this).toggleClass('fa-caret-up');});
```

This just toggles the CSS class of the icon I want to show. I add the class *toggler* to the item I want to apply this to. This can be added onto any item you want to toggle an icon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **2021** update for this very old question...

**Bootstrap 5**

Icon agnostic solution (doesn't use a specific icon lib) using CSS up/down triangles...

```
/* for up.down arrows after collapse items with submenus */
[data-bs-toggle="collapse"]::after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.255em;
  vertical-align: 0.255em;
  content: "";
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0.3em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.3em solid;
  border-left: 0.3em solid transparent;
}

[data-bs-toggle="collapse"].collapsed::after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.255em;
  vertical-align: 0.255em;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0.3em solid transparent;
  border-top: 0.3em solid;
  border-left: 0.3em solid transparent;
}
```

[Demo using sidebar with collapse submenu](https://www.codeply.com/p/ra7vfR5Jcz)

Comment: Thanks Zim!

And to everyone that's responded, thank you for your input! It's interesting how this post is still kind of relevant, thanks again everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Another no-javascript solution that uses the collapse functionality itself:

```
/* Prevent block display and transition animation */
.expand-icon.collapse.in,
.collapse-icon.collapse.in {
  display: inline; }
.expand-icon.collapsing {
  display: none; }

/* HTML Toggler with glyphicons */
<a data-toggle="collapse" href=".my-collapse">
 <span class="my-collapse collapse-icon collapse in">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span>
 </span>
 <span class="my-collapse expand-icon collapse">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-expand"></span>   
 </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a CSS-only (and icon-free) solution using Bootstrap 3 I had to do a bit of fiddling based on Martin Wickman's answer above.

I didn't use the accordion-* notation because it's done with panels in BS3.

Also, I had to include in the initial HTML aria-expanded="true" on the item that's open at page load.

Here is the CSS I used.

```
.accordion-toggle:hover { text-decoration: none; }
.accordion-toggle:hover span, .accordion-toggle:hover strong { text-decoration: underline; }
.accordion-toggle:before { font-size: 25px; }
.accordion-toggle[data-toggle="collapse"]:before { content: "+"; margin-right: 0px; }
.accordion-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:before { content: "-"; margin-right: 0px; }
```

Here is my sanitized HTML:

```
<div id="acc1">    
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#acc1" href="#acc1-1">Title 1
                    </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id=“acc1-1” class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Text 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#acc1” href=“#acc1-2”>Title 2
                    </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id=“acc1-2” class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Text 2                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest possible answer.

**HTML**

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-quote-group" href="#collapseQuote">
    <span class="toggle-icon glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span>
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
     $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function () {
     $(this).find('span.toggle-icon').toggleClass('glyphicon-collapse-up glyphicon-collapse-down');
     })
 })
 </script>
```

And of course, you can use anything for a selector instead of anchor tag `a` and you can also use specific selector instead of `this` if your icon lies outside your clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that creates a section that is expandable using somewhat material design, bootstrap 4.5/5 alpha and entirely non-javascript.

**Style for head section**

```
<style>
[data-toggle="collapse"] .fa:before {
    content: "\f077";
}

[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .fa:before {
    content: "\f078";
}
</style>
```

**Body html**

```
<div class="pt-3 pb-3" style="border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee; border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee; cursor: pointer;">
<a href="#expandId" class="text-dark float-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="expandId">
    <i class="fa" aria-hidden="false"></i>
</a>
<a href="#expandId" class="text-dark collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="expandId">Expand Header</a>
<div class="collapse" id="expandId">
    CONTENT GOES IN HERE
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a change icon click on the accordions item open by adding flowing CSS property here are content properties to show/open the icon & after close it shows the default icon.

If you want to chnage the icon please add this icon in the content property like an arrow, symbol. The first dropdown-toggle::after is for the default behavior of accordions and the second collapsed::after is used after the open accordions icon shown through the content

```
 .dropdown-toggle::after {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 20px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      float: right;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      content: "▾";
    }
    
    .collapsed::after {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 20px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      margin-top: 10px;
      float: right;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
      content: "▸";        
    }
```

In accordion use by

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
        Number 1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        The first description of item number 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
        Number 2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        The second description of item number 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree">
        Number 3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
      <div class="accordion-body">
         The third description of item number 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!