# Using jQuery in Angular: anything bad about this?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using Bootstrap accordion in an Angular web app and saw a post addressing a bug on the switching of collapse/expand icons (check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882404/twitter-bootstrap-accordion-icon-doesnt-change)).

The post mentions a fix involving simple jQuery.  Here is that code:

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $('.accordion-toggle').not(this).addClass('collapsed');
    }
});
```

Is there anything inadvisable about using the above jQuery fix in my Angular web app? If so, what is a recommended fix for this bug using Angular?

Comment: [That is why angular ui bootstrap has an accordion.](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) SO that you dont need to access DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze this by parts:

1° This

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
```

should actually be something like this in your dom:

```
<div ng-click="toggleAccordion()">Toggle accordion!</div>
<div ng-class="{collapsed: isToggled}"><!-- data --></div>
```

2° And this

```
$('.accordion-toggle').not(this).addClass('collapsed');
```

should actually be something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.toggleAccordion = function(){
    $scope.isToggled = !$scope.isToggled;
}
```

Doing this, the solution is more declarative instead of imperative. Cheers!

PD: Another way to do this would be full dom but i don't like it as much.

```
<div ng-click="isToggled = !isToggled">Toggle accordion!</div>
<div ng-class="{collapsed: isToggled}"><!-- data --></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to vote this as the best answer.  It's clean and appropriate.  However, arising from PSL's comment above I am now looking at the Angular implementation of Bootstrap.  Perhaps I'll keep this as a backup, in case there's reason the Angular implementation cannont be used.

Comment: It's ok don't worry. I'm here answering questions just because i love teaching and explaining stuff! Reputation points and checked answers it's just a bonus that comes together with the site :P