# How to determine if a bootstrap collapse is opening or closing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a bootstrap collapse how can I determine from a click event wether the collapse is opening or closing?

Here is my click event or maybe there is a better way then to use a click event?

```
$(document).on("click", "a.register-student-link", function() {
    // do some stuff to check if opening or closing
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id=@space.EventId class="register-student-link" data-toggle="collapse" href=@spaceIdWith aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                                    Register Student
                                                </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 42):

Bootstrap uses the aria-expanded attribute to show true or false if the region is collapsed or not.

```
var isExpanded = $(collapsableRegion).attr("aria-expanded");
```

Comment: For anyone struggling with getting this to work; make sure you initialise the `aria-expanded` attribute to `true` or `false` in the HTML!

Comment: This might be true and probably helped you, seeing this answer is made by the OP. However, if I read through the question itself (which I had too), this does not answer it at all. The answer below (with shown.bs.collapse) works like a charm and answer the true question of "how to determine the collapse event". I think that should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 35):

Try:

```js
$('#collapseDiv').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   console.log("Opened")
});

$('#collapseDiv').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   console.log("Closed")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <a id=@space.EventId class="register-student-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDiv" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Register Student</a>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseDiv">This is the collapsible content!</div>
```

(based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18147817/2033574 (Kevin mentioned) and http://www.bootply.com/73101)

Answer (score 26):

I needed a way to determine if the element was collapsed BEFORE actually collapsing. Whereas the event listeners only trigger afterwards.

```
//Will return true if uncollapsed
$('#collapseDiv').hasClass('in');

//Will return true if in the process of collapsing
$('#collapseDiv').hasClass('collapsing');

//Will return true if collapsed
$('#collapseDiv').hasClass('collapse');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can watch the event `hidden.bs.collapse`

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyeuvx1d/

Comment: bootstrap collapse doesn' t have this

Comment: Here is another post with a simlilar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147338/twitter-bootstrap-3-0-icon-change-on-collapse

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!$("#id").hasClass('show')){
    alert("Uncollapsed");
}
else {
    alert("Collapsed");
}
```

for Bootstrap 4