# Bootstrap collapsible nested nav jquery applies to more than one targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nested tree nav with collapsible (using Bootstrap 3.0 Collapse) content with icons insted of default list-style. I want to change the icon when the collapsed area is extended. **But when I close the inner collapse area, all of icons change back.**

I'm a javascript newbie and took the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147338/twitter-bootstrap-3-0-icon-change-on-collapse) post. It adds class `.icon-right` to `li` element on `shown.bs.collapse` and removes it on `hidden.bs.collapse`. But it does't apply to only targeted element.

How to edit it to target only icon that is beeing closed?

Here is the code on CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPyrQg.

HTML

```
<ul class="ls-nav">
      <li id="expand1">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseContent1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseContent1">Lorem Ipsum
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseContent1">
          <ul class="ls-inner">
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li id="expand2">
              <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseContent2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseContent2">Lorem Ipsum
               </a>
               <div class="collapse" id="collapseContent2">
              <ul class="ls-inner-dot">
                <li class="active">Lorem</li>
                <li>Lorem</li>
              </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>Lorem</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
    </ul>
```

JS

```
      $('#collapseContent1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("#expand1").addClass("icon-down");
  });

  $('#collapseContent1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("#expand1").removeClass("icon-down");
  });

  $('#collapseContent2').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("#expand2").addClass("icon-down");
  });

  $('#collapseContent2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("#expand2").removeClass("icon-down");
  });
```

I've been searching for two days and I would be so happy if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your `aria-controls` as a class to your `<a>` tags, then toggleClass of `.icon-down` on your `expand` unique ID's. Here is a working demo with code:

Here is a demo to illustrate how this works:

```
       <ul class="ls-nav">
          <li id="expand1" >
            <a class="collapseContent1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseContent1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseContent1">Lorem Ipsum
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseContent1">
              <ul class="ls-inner">
                <li>Lorem</li>
                <li>Lorem</li>
                <li>Lorem</li>
                <li>Lorem</li>
                <li id="expand2">
                  <a class="collapseContent2" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapseContent2" href="#collapseContent2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseContent2">Lorem Ipsum
                   </a>
                   <div class="collapse" id="collapseContent2">
                  <ul class="ls-inner-dot">
                    <li class="active">Lorem</li>
                    <li>Lorem</li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>Lorem</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
      </ul>
```

JS:

```
  $('.collapseContent2').on('click', function() {
    $("#expand2").toggleClass("icon-down");
  });

    $('.collapseContent1').on('click', function() {
    $("#expand1").toggleClass("icon-down");
  });
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/RWqbJL?editors=101)

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation, you really helped me. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

when the event on the `#collapseContent2`is triggered, the same type of event is triggered on`#collapseContent1` because `#collapseContent2` is part of `#collapseContent1`. This is called event bubbling. You can stop an event bubbling up the DOM by calling jQuerys [event.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) function.

```
$('#collapseContent2, #collapseContent1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).closest("#expand2").removeClass("icon-down");
});
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpwRWY)

This would also be an easy fix for your problem.