# How to change the logo collapse when the link is unfolded?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I created an accordion link with Bootstrap, I wish to have a logo "Plus" when accordion is closed and a logo "Less" when the arcordon is open. Here is my html code :

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <i class="fa fa-object-group fa-lg"></i> Ses contenus <span class="badge">12</span>
        <div class="panel-button"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i></div>
        </h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body"><dd>{{ drupal_view('profil_page_contenu_utilisateur', 'block_1') }}</dd></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css but it does not work :

```
body.path-profile .field--name-dynamic-block-fieldprofile-profil-page-contenu-utilisateur .panel-button div.collapse > a i:before {
    content: '\f055';
}

body.path-profile .field--name-dynamic-block-fieldprofile-profil-page-contenu-utilisateur .panel-button div.collapse > a[aria-expanded=true] i:before {
    content: '\f056';
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example or fiddle of your code so we can try to troubleshoot?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? > https://jsfiddle.net/tszmeasy/

Comment: @FelixMichaelCervin here is the page concerned https://www.s1biose.com/profil/mathieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap made Collapse using it's own Jquery.

Its better for you use Jquery too.

see this question :

[Twitter bootstrap 3.0 icon change on collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147338/twitter-bootstrap-3-0-icon-change-on-collapse)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#collapse1").on("hide.bs.collapse", function(){
    $("#icon").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>');
  });
  $("#collapse1").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
    $("#icon").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
  });
});
```

```css
#icon{
float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Collapsible Panel</h2>
  <p>Click on the collapsible panel to open and close it.</p>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel<p id="icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></p></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```