# Bootstrap UI - How can I change the accordion header icon, on tab expanded?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

How can I change the accordion header icon, on tab expanded ?

Accordion plunke URL is : http://plnkr.co/edit/7HMhoHk9AWyBAHALgD0P?p=preview

```
 <accordion-group>
        <accordion-heading>
            I can have markup, too! <i class="icon-check"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

So basically I want to change the icon-check class  to let's say icon-uncheck, when the  tab is expanded

Comment: Bootstrap probably emits some events when its widgets change state - check the bootstrap docs for the Accordion control and change the icon in them? (This *should* be the Collapsible widget: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse)

Answer (score 6):

This should do what you want..

```
  <accordion-group is-open="$parent.isOpen">
    <accordion-heading>
        I can have markup, too! 
        <i ng-class="{'icon-minus':isOpen,'icon-plus':!isOpen}"></i>
    </accordion-heading>
    This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
  </accordion-group>
```

<s>Here's a working plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kxKVsqHa1a64RvOUbVcM?p=preview</s>

**UPDATE**

The above code is not properly working. It collapses/expands all groups in the accordion at once.

Have a look at this Plunker for a better solution:
    http://plnkr.co/edit/RQKAoY04eVj1ysIikRxU?p=preview

Comment: I'm not the person who voted this down, but the solution does not precisely work. Your plunker code only has one accordion group, so it appears to work. With more than one, this solution actually opens all accordion groups at once. See: http://plnkr.co/edit/E5lHAUWngy4HsmlGBMBg?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, i didn't recognize this. After fiddling around a while i found a solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/RQKAoY04eVj1ysIikRxU?p=preview

Comment: i am getting an icon by default. Any idea how to remove it?

Comment: @Sana Just remove the line with the i-tag.
`<i ng-class="{'icon-minus-sign':groups[$index].open,'icon-plus-sign':!groups[$index].open }"></i>`

Answer (score 2):

**For change icon**

```
<accordion close-others="true" is-open="group.open">
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <accordion-heading>
            <i ng-class="{'icon-minus-sign':groups[$index].open,'icon-plus-sign':!groups[$index].open }"></i>
           [{{$index + 1}}] {{group.title}}
        </accordion-heading>
        {{group.content}}
     </accordion-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try adding a script to your page that targets the accordion-heading class to change the  class attribute to your desired icon. maybe you can refer to these posts for some insight into how to do this.

[Twitter Bootstrap accordion icon doesnt change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882404/twitter-bootstrap-accordion-icon-doesnt-change)

[Adding open/closed icon to Twitter Bootstrap collapsibles (accordions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778703/adding-open-closed-icon-to-twitter-bootstrap-collapsibles-accordions)